# SOLVED:How can i get a decimal like 0.9 to be a percentage so the number i have goes up by 0.9 percent?

Tags: python, percentage

I'm doing a school project and we ask the user for a population in millions and we also ask for a growth rate.  The rate is a percentage, for example if the number is 0.9 the population should go up by 0.9 percent or if it was 4.31, it would go up by 4.31 percent. I am having trouble converting 0.9(decimal) to 0.9(percent).

Comment: Can you give more background, such as where has 0.9 (decimal or percent) comes from?

Comment: Welcome! First of all, please, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The user gives us the population of a country in millions and also gives us the growth or decay rate. If the user gives us 0.9 for the growth rate the population should increase by 0.9%. The percentage is then used to calculate future years population

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show some code trials for other readers to get a better context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

Let's understand what *x%* means. *x%* is *x parts/100parts*. So, 50% is 50/100.
Think of it this way. Find out 50% of the given population can be written as
*50/100=X/given_population*.

*X=(50/100)*given_population* here *X* is 50% of the given population.

Since in your case you want it's **percentage rise** so add the given percentage to the present population.
If given population is *pop* and rise is *X%*.

> New_population=pop+(*X%* of pop)

```
new_pop=pop+(pop*(percentage/100))
```

Answer (score 1):

To combine the answers from both [Bendik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6547224/bendik-knapstad) and [Ch3ster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster).  This is 'just mathematics'.

Start with an easy example:  What is one tenth of one hundred?

It's 10, right?  One tenth, may be written as a fraction like so: 1/10 and as a decimal, as 0.1.  We can think also that one third of nine is three.  Where "one third of [a number]" means "What is [a number] divided by 3".

So we could rewrite our very first question as: What is `100/10`?

Now, let's consider that I go running, and in 2 hours, I cover 20 km.  How do I calculate my average speed?  I divide 20 km by 2 hours.  This gives me an average speed of 10 km per hour, meaning that I travelled roughly 10km in the first hour, and then roughly 10 km again in the second hour.  So we can think that the "per" means roughly, "divided by". `20 (km) divided by 2 (hours) --> 10 km per hour`

If you then consider that 'percent' has a literal meaning of 'per hundred' then we could ask:  What is 10 %?  Which we can re-write as ten per hundred, or `10/100 = 1/10 = 0.1`

So, what is `0.9% of 1000`?  From the above, can work out that 0.9% is `0.9/100`, or 0.009.  So how can we find a number which when divided by 1000 gives 0.009?  We multiply, 0.009 and 1000: `0.009*1000 = 9`

We can make a 'general version' of this as:

`population_change = (rate / 100) * original_population`

So the `new_population = original_population + population_change`

or, `new_population = original_population + (rate / 100) * original_population`

and we can simplify this a little to:
`new_population = original_population * (1 + (rate/100) )`

Comment: Now that's an analytical way of explaining it, gj!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I had the the percentage calculated before and I never did anything with it besides printing it so the population looked way to small. Now I understand that you have to incorporate the population with the population change. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is more a maths question but just divide it by 100 so 0.9 becomes 0.009 then multiply your number by (1+0.009) to increment by .9 %